# Unity3d - How to get Animator's Layer -->Sub-State --> State namehash?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the following structure:

(Layer) "Base Layer" -->
   (Sub-State) "Jump_Fall_Roll" -->
      (State) "Roll"

```
static int rollState = Animator.StringToHash("What to put here??");

private Animator anim;
private AnimatorStateInfo currentBaseState;

void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    currentBaseState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

    if (currentBaseState.nameHash == rollState) {
        Debug.Log ("ROLL nameHash worked"); //Not working
    }
    if (currentBaseState.IsName("Roll")) {
        Debug.Log ("ROLL IsName worked"); //Working.......
    }
}
```

I tryed every possible combinaison of parents/states for the nameHash, but it never worked...

> The name should be in the form Layer.Name, for example "Base.Idle".

[AnimatorStateInfo.IsName doc from Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.IsName.html)

So, why is my first case not working? And how can the second case work??

I'm really confused.

**EDIT**

Screenshot of my Animator view
[image: Screenshot of my Animator view]

I did try `static int rollState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Roll");`

Then `Debug.Log (currentBaseState.nameHash + ", " + rollState);`

Will output

> 1094782407, -1476868190

When I'm in the roll state.
rollState NEVER = currentBaseState.nameHash.

I did test this with the Idle state, which works perfectly like this :

`static int rollState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Idle");`

I can't see what the structure is for sub-states, really frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously have no Idea what changed in my project, but I tryed

```
static int rollState = Animator.StringToHash ("Jump_Fall_Roll.Roll");
```

again (I had tested it before I post this question and spend hours trying to resolve it) and it managed to work..........

**So, for Sub-States, do not include the Layer name in the hash, only the parent Sub-State of your State.**

I did not test for nested Sub-States.

Thank you to those who tryed to help me

Answer (score 5):

In the most up-to-date version of 5.3.4 at time of writing, the question can be partially answered as follows.

First of all, there is no `nameHash` any more. The closest variable to it is `shortNameHash`. It is recommended to use `fullPathHash` instead as will be explained shortly. `shortNameHash` is like the bare file name in OS, while `fullPathHash`, as its name suggests, contains layer name as path before the state name. Here is an example to use both of them to identify the current state:

```
int baseState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Idle");
int short_baseState = Animator.StringToHash("Idle");
int subState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Jump_Fall_Roll.Roll");
int short_subState = Animator.StringToHash("Roll");

...

AnimatorStateInfo s = myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
Debug.Log(s.fullPathHash + ", " + baseState);   //they are equal at Idle state in base layer
Debug.Log(s.shortNameHash + ", " + short_baseState);   //they are equal at Idle state in base layer
Debug.Log(s.fullPathHash + ", " + subState);   //they are equal at Roll state in sub-state machine
Debug.Log(s.shortNameHash + ", " + short_subState);   //they are equal at Roll state in sub-state machine
```

From the above example we can see that `shortNameHash` works for bare state name, no matter the state is regular one in base layer, or a state in the sub-state machine. But `fullPathHash` works only when layer path is properly prefixed before the state name. If we are sure there is no duplicate state names in different state machines, `shortNameHash` is good because it is short, but this assumption does not always hold in a large complex animator controller, so I would like to recommend using `fullPathHash` all the time.

I call this answer "partial" because we have to make sure the layer id passed to GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo is 0, i.e., the "current working layer" (like the `pwd` command in linux) should be the base layer. The above path name convention fails if we pass 1 to it. I don't have time to guess what the path name should be in layer 1. Any complement in this regard is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The string to pass in `Animator.StringToHash` should include **layer's name and state's name**.

So to correctly generate the hash it should be:

```
int rollState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Roll");
```

Comment: Debug.Log (currentBaseState.nameHash + ", " + rollState);
Outputs:
1094782407, -1476868190

During the Roll, it is not working, I will update my question with some more info