# How can get animations from the sub state machine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public static class IListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shuffles the element order of the specified list.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> ts)
    {
        var count = ts.Count;
        var last = count - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < last; ++i)
        {
            var r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(i, count);
            var tmp = ts[i];
            ts[i] = ts[r];
            ts[r] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

public class PlayAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AnimationClip[] clips;
    private Animator animator;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Get the animator component
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        // Get all available clips
        clips = animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayRandomly());
    }

    private IEnumerator PlayRandomly()
    {
        var clipList = clips.ToList();

        while (true)
        {
            clipList.Shuffle();

            foreach (var randClip in clipList)
            {
                animator.Play(randClip.name);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(randClip.length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will get all animations from the states in the regular top controller state machine. But I created a sub state machine name Magic StateMachine.

And I want to get all the animation clips from the states only inside Magic StateMachine.

Screenshot of the animator controller:

[image: Animator Controller]

And a screenshot of the sub state machine and the states I want to get the animation clips from and play randomly:

[image: Sub state machine]

Comment: Can you confirm that animationClips does not already contain also the substates? Maybe you could print out `foreach(var n in clips.Select(c => c.name).ToList()){ Debug.Log(n);}` to be sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3d - How to get Animator's Layer -->Sub-State --> State namehash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956518/unity3d-how-to-get-animators-layer-sub-state-state-namehash)

Comment: @derHugo Oops sorry, I didn't check before but it's including already the substates. I justn eed to figure now how to play only the substates depending in my game when I need to play only the substates. So maybe I do need to get only the substates to another list. If there was a easy way to mark/tag specific states.